# not found exception is not working in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

my code

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(long? Workrequestid, string fileexist){ throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound,"this item does not exist"));}
```

error i am getting like

```
{  "message": "Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details."
```

}

according to me i need the message like "this item already exist". please help me

Comment: You're throwing an exception, and getting an exception. How puzzling! The code is doing exactly what you told it! Can you [edit] to explain what unexpected about this?

Comment: why message "this item does not exist" is not coming

Comment: Are you sure you called service in the right way?
Can you post your call?

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation does work as expected. Are you calling the API correctly? I've used TestController and posting to the following Uri and it works:

> http://localhost:8075/api/test?workrequestId=1&fileexist=test

However, are you sure you want to explicitly throw an exception? When returning an IHttpActionResult it would be cleaner to simply return a 404 in the following way:

```
return this.NotFound();
```

Returning a NotFound error is telling the calling client all it needs to know, returning "this item does not exist" is redundant.

As there is no implementation on your code sample it's difficult to see your intention for the API other that it's a post. Depending on the circumstances, ***if appropriate***, you could also return:

```
return this.BadRequest("this item does not exist.");
```